# Modified version of generelized Hechler forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm looking at a modified version of the generalized Hechler forcing:

Let $\kappa$ be inaccessible, and fix some $s:\kappa \to \kappa$ strictly monotone taking value in the regular cardinals.* Conditions in the forcing are of the form $(f,g)$ where for some $\alpha<\kappa$, $f$ is a function from $\alpha$ to $\kappa$, $g$ is a function from $\kappa \smallsetminus \alpha$ to $\kappa$, and for all $\xi < \kappa$, either $s(\xi) > f(\xi)$ or $s(\xi) > g(\xi)$ (whichever of them makes sense). A condition $(f,g)$ is stronger then $(f',g')$ if $f' \subset f$ and for all $\xi \in \mathrm{dom}{g'}$ either $f(\xi) \ge g'(\xi)$ or $g(\xi) \ge g'(\xi)$ (again, whichever of them makes sense).

If we remove the restriction given by $s$, the forcing adds a function dominating all functions from $V$ in $^\kappa\kappa$ (mod bounded).

Say we force with the restriction given by $s$. Then the forcing adds a function dominating all functions from $V$ in $\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)$. Does it also add a dominating function for $^\kappa\kappa$? What about the other way around - when we force without restricting using $s$, do we also add a dominating function for $\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)$?

* It might be similar if we take $\kappa$ to be any regular cardinal, and ask that $s$ takes values in limit ordinals. But I defined it this way because I'm not sure, and because the broader setting  in which this question came up has $\kappa$ being supercompact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The restricted version never adds a dominating function in $\kappa^\kappa$ (mod bounded) (Edit: if $\kappa$ is weakly compact) and it is consistent (relative to a Mahlo cardinal) that the unrestricted forcing does not add a dominating function in $\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)$ (mod bounded).

Lets first check the first part. Let us call the restricted by $s$ forcing $\mathbb P_s$. The crucial points are that

- Any $(f, g), (f^\prime, g^\prime)\in\mathbb P_s$ with $f=f^\prime$ are compatible.
- For any $\alpha<\kappa$ there are ${<}\kappa$-many $f$ with $\mathrm{dom}(f)\subseteq\alpha$ such that $(f, g)\in\mathbb P_s$ for some $g$.

Note that the second point is not true for the unrestricted forcing. Now let $\dot h$ be a name for a function $h:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$. For $\alpha<\kappa$ let $\mathbb P_s^\alpha$ be the set of $(f, g)\in\mathbb P_s$ with $\mathrm{dom}(f)\subseteq\alpha$. The above implies that for any $i,\alpha<\kappa$ there are ${<}\kappa$-many $\beta$ such that some $(f, g)\in\mathbb P_s^\alpha$ decides $\dot h(\check i)$ to be $\beta$. Let us define
$$F_i:\mathbb P_s\rightarrow\kappa,\ F_i((f, g))=\mathrm{min}\{\alpha\mid \exists (f^\prime, g^\prime)\in\mathbb P_s^\alpha\text{ deciding }\dot h(\check i)\wedge (f^\prime, g^\prime)\leq (f, g)\}$$
and
$$H:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa,\ H(i)=\mathrm{sup}\{\beta\mid \exists (f, g)\in\mathbb P_s^{\mathrm{sup}F_i[\mathbb P_s^i]}\text{ deciding }\dot h(\check i)\text{ as }\beta\}+1$$

We must check that $H$ is well-defined. As j3M points out, it seems non-trivial that $F_i[\mathbb P_s^i]$ is always bounded in $\kappa$ (see the comments). We make use of the weak compactness of $\kappa$ to prove this:

So suppose $\mathrm{sup}F_j[\mathbb P_s^j]=\kappa$. There must then be a single first component $f$ so that $F_j((f, g))$ gets arbitrarily large by varying $g$. For convenience, say $f=\emptyset$. Let
$$X_\alpha=\{g\in\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)\mid F_j(f, g)\geq\alpha\}$$
Observe that membership of $g$ in$ X_\alpha$ depends only on $g\upharpoonright\alpha$, so (abusing notation) we will say $g\upharpoonright\alpha\in X_\alpha$.
Consider the tree $T$ whose $\alpha$-th level $T_\alpha$ is exactly
$$T_\alpha=X_\alpha\cap\prod_{i<\alpha}s(i)$$
and is ordered by end-extension. Then $T$ is indeed a tree, all levels have size ${<}\kappa$ and by our choice of $f$, $T$ has height $\kappa$. By weak compactness, there is a cofinal branch through $T$. We may think of that branch as a function $g\in\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa} X_\alpha$. But now $F_j((f, g))\geq\kappa$, meaning $(f, g)$ has no extension deciding the value of $\dot h(\check j)$. This is clearly a contradiction.

Finally $H$ is not dominated (mod bounded) by $\dot h^G$ for any generic $G$ (as the generic will often "pick minimal extensions deciding some value of $\dot h$").

For the second part, suppose that $\kappa$ is a Mahlo cardinal and $s(i)$ is simply the $i$-th regular cardinal. The set $S=\{i<\kappa\mid i=s(i)\}$ is stationary in $\kappa$ and note that any $f\in\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)$ is regressive on $S$. Assume that after forcing with the unrestricted generalised Hechler forcing $\mathbb P$ at $\kappa$, there is $f\in\prod_{i<\kappa}s(i)$ dominating all such functions in $V$ (mod bounded). Then $f^{-1}(\{\xi\})$ is bounded and thus non-stationary for any $\xi<\kappa$. By Fodor's Lemma this means that $S$ is no longer stationary. However, $\mathbb P$ is ${<}\kappa$-closed and so preserves the stationarity of $S$, contradiction.

Comment: Your first bullet item seems not quite correct. For example, if $f$ is an extension of $f'$, then compatibility requires that the new part of $f$ be above $g'$, so it depends on $g'$. It is, however, true that any two conditions with the same first component are compatible, and that's all you needed in the rest of the proof.

Comment: You are right, I totally overlooked that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!
There is some part I'm having trouble with though, which relates to the comment of @AndreasBlass . Maybe some simple argument that I'm missing: Even if two conditions $p,p'\in\mathbb{P}_s^i$ are compatible, their minimal extensions that decide $\dot{h}(i)$ might not be, and in particular, we might have $F_i(p) \neq F_i(p')$. So what prevents $F_i[\mathbb{P}_s^i]$ from being unbounded in $\kappa$?

Comment: @j3M For each $\beta$ such that some $(f,g)\in\mathbb P^\alpha_s$ forces $\dot h(\check i)=\check\beta$, choose one such $(f,g)$. All these chosen conditions are pairwise incompatible (because they force different values for $\dot h(\check i)$), so they have different first components $f$, and so there are $<\kappa$ of them.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, that part I understand. However, when we define $F_i$ we are asking for the minimal $\alpha$ such that there is an extension $(f,g)\geq (f',g') \in \mathbb{P}_s^\alpha$ deciding $\dot{h}(i)$. We might still have $(f, g_0), (f,g_1) \in \mathbb{P}_s^i$ (same first coordinate) such that the minimal extension deciding $\dot{h}(i)$ lies in a different $\mathbb{P}_s^\alpha$ (i.e. different $\alpha$'s)....

Comment: ....So the by varying the function in the second coordinate, we may get that $F_i[\mathbb{P}^i_s]$ is unbounded in $\kappa$. It's true that for a fixed $\alpha$ there $<\kappa$ many possibilities for $\beta$ if $\dot{h}(i)$ decided by conditions in $\mathbb{P}_s^\alpha$. But when we take the $\mathrm{sup}$ over all the possible $\beta$'s, we actually don't keep this $\alpha$ fixed.

Comment: I agree that you raise a legitimate concern there. I believe it is possible to show that $F_i[\mathbb P_s^i]$ is bounded in case $\kappa$ is weakly compact.

Comment: The argument for that is now included in my answer. It would be interesting if anyone could remove the large cardinal assumptions.

Comment: @AndreasLietz Very nice! Also, I find it interesting as well and 'll be thinking about ways to use weaker assumptions.

Comment: It turns out that the weak compactness cannot be removed from the argument. In $L$, Hechler forcing below the map $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^+$ will add a $\kappa$-dominating function if $\kappa$ is not weakly compact (but inaccessible).